# Alternating-direction implicit method for Laplace's initial value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> **Problem 1.** Consider the Laplace's initial value problem
> $$
> \begin{gathered}
> \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0,0<x, y<4 \\
> u(x, 0)=u(0, y)=u(4, y)=0, u(x, 4)=\frac{1}{2} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \pi x\right)
> \end{gathered}
> $$
> The exact solution is given as,
> $$
> u(x, y)=\frac{1}{2 \sinh \pi} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \pi x\right) \sinh \left(\frac{1}{4} \pi y\right)
> $$

The Difference equation is, $$
u_{i-1, j}+u_{i+1, j}+u_{i, j-1}+u_{i, j+1}+4 u_{i, j}=0
$$
I guess the idea behind the ADI method is to split the finite difference equations into two, one with the x-derivative taken implicitly and the next with the y-derivative taken implicitly,
$$
u_{i-1, j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}-4 u_{i, j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}+u_{i+1, j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=-u_{i, j-1}^m-u_{i, j+1}^m\tag1
$$

$$
u_{i, j-1}^{(m+1)}-4 u_{i, j}^{(m+1)}+u_{i, j+1}^{(m+1)}=-u_{i-1, j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}-u_{i+1, j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\tag2
$$

Using the ADI method with a grid step size $h=1$ and starting values $0$.
$$
u_{i-1 . j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}-4 u_{i . j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}+u_{i+1, j}^{\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=-u_{i, j-1}^{(m)}-u_{i, j+1}^{(m)}
$$
Now, for $t=1, m=0$, and starting with $j=1$ and for $i=1,2,3$ in matrix, we have
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-4 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -4
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
u_{1,1}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{2,1}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{3,1}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right) \Rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{l}
u_{1,1}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{2,1}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{3,1}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$
for $j=2, i=1,2,3$ in matrix, we have
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{1,2}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{2,2}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{3,2}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$
also for $j=3, i=1,2,3$ in matrix, we have
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{1,3}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{2,3}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
u_{3,3}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0.1367295401695 \\
0.1933647700848 \\
0.136725401695
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now, alternating the direction using equation $(2)$, by choosing $i = 1$ and for $j = 1, 2, 3$ we get,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-4 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -4
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
u_{1,1}^{1} \\
u_{1,2}^{1} \\
u_{1,3}^{1}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
0 \\
-u_{2,3}^{\frac12}-u_{1,4}^1
\end{array}\right) \Rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{l}
u_{1,1}^{1} \\
u_{1,2}^{1} \\
u_{1,3}^{1}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
9.76639\times10^{-3} \\
0.03906558 \\
0.1464959
\end{array}\right)
$$

Is my approach being correct? It seems like my solution is not so accurate compare to original solution.